# mvn dependency:get -Ddest parameter in Linux

Tags: linux, maven, ubuntu, maven-plugin

I´m using the `mvn dependency:get` to download some specific *.jar (latest Release Version) files on Linux Ubuntu.

I am using the following command:

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:RELEASE:jar -DrepoUrl=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2 -Ddest=/home/dev/workspace/"
```

The artifact is downloaded as expected, but only to the local maven repository and not to copied to the specified Location. I have also tried using

```
-Ddest=home/dev/workspace/
-Ddest=/home/dev/workspace
```

But there is no difference in the Result.

I know there is the possibility to use dependency:copy, but therefore i would need a pom.xml (which i don´t want to create only for the copy command).

Thanks for your help

Comment: You shouls use `dependency:copy` because the `destination` is deprecated. Apart from that why you don't use the usual build to download those artifacts (via dependencies)...

Comment: I am preparing the source code for a code analyzing tool, which means, i need to get the *.jar Files for ~100 projects. So i do not need to build the projects, i only need to add the jar files to the project, for code analyzation

Comment: You can try with the following plugin instead https://github.com/maven-download-plugin/maven-download-plugin from google.

Comment: @drgn is there any possibility to change the default repository from repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 to repo1.maven.apache.org/maven2

Comment: I think repo1.maven.apache.org/maven2 is a mirror to repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 by the following link http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.meta/repository-metadata.xml

Answer (score 3):

I have given an examples. Please check.

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=org.apache.maven:maven-core:2.2.1:jar:sources -DremoteRepositories=http://repo1.maven.apache.org/maven2 -Ddest=/home/dev/workspace/something.jar
```

You can also use `dependency:copy` as

Artifacts can also be resolved by specifying the classifier and optionally type. Type is only used with the classifier and defaults to java-sources. When the classifier is set, the list of dependencies is used as the base to resolve artifacts with the classifier and type.

**For example:**

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -Dclassifier=sources
```

will try to find the sources for all dependencies and copy them.
For more data command line like:

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies [optional params]
```

Resource Link:

1. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html
2. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html

**UPDATE:**

use **"-Ddest=path/to/my.jar";** otherwise, it is just copied to your local `~/.m2/repository` (makes it look like nothing happened).

See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html#destination

example=>

```
 mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.5.1:get 
 -DremoteRepositories=repo.maven.apache.org
 -Dartifact=org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.1
 -Ddest=ant-1.8.1.jar
```

(result: ant-1.8.1.jar in current directory)

Comment: dependency:get does not work because of ':jar:sources' (there it says, invalid artifact, you must specify groupId:artifactId:version:[packaging]) it only works if I only take ':jar', but the jar file is not loaded /home/dev/workspace. For the mvn depedency:copy, i need to specify a pom.xml file, which i don´t want to create (i have to download *.jar files for about 100 projects, but don´t need to build the project), i only need to download jar files and copy them to the right directory